# Notepad++ - How to change contents of a line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Attempting to get this work, I've tried the other responses and they just don't work.

Currently I have a bunch of files that have;
`"craftgroup" : [ "tool1", "tool2", "tool3" ]`

I'm attempting to get it to change all the files into
`"craftgroup" : [ "mastertool" ]`

but I can't seem to get it to actually work because the regex isn't working and I have over 650 files to change >.>

Edit; The Links I tried were;
[How to delete specific lines on Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad)
[Notepad++ Replace new line inside text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861851/notepad-replace-new-line-inside-text)
[Notepad++ Search And Replace Multiple Text Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305302/notepad-search-and-replace-multiple-text-lines)

None of them have worked, I just need to replace the entire line if that's easier.

Thanks m0shit0 that worked, other ones for some reason kept saying "can't find text"

Comment: "Other Responses" are you referring to another post?  Please provide the link.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. What regex have you tried? How should it look like? How does it look like?

Comment: And how we're supposed to know how  "tool1", "tool2", "tool3" >> "mastertool"? Do you mean all entries are **exactly** like this or is this an example?

Comment: @m0skit0 All of the lines have different tools for a example and need to be mastertool, sorry for making it look derpish just kinda tired after doing this for a hour and not a single bit closer.

Comment: @user2813035 So do you want to replace `"craftgroup": WHATEVER` with the **exact** string `"craftgroup": [ "mastertool" ]`? Is "mastertool" a keyword for something or is that the REAL string in ALL instances?

Comment: Yup, all just need to be replaced to "craftgroup": [ "mastertool" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. I understand that you only want to replace lines that have `craftgroup`.

Find: `"craftgroup" : \[(.*?)\]`

Replace: `"craftgroup" : \[ "mastertool" \]`

Note: Notepad++ 6.5